# BeautifulSoup not reading ill-formed html

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I was learning BeautifulSoup. It wasn't reading some of the sites properly. I found that the reason was some html attributes were ill-formed. For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
        <html>
        <head><title>Test</title></head>
        <body>
        <p id="paraone"align="center">some content <b>para1</b>.<!--there is no space before 'align' attribute -->
        <p id="paratwo" align="blah">some content <b>para2</b>
        </html>
    """
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print "soup:", soup
```

I think BeautifulSoup designed not to read ill-formed html. If so, is there any other module to read the above given html? Can't we parse ill-formed web sites?

Comment: How do you want BeautifulSoup to behave differently?

Comment: There will be ill-formed web sites(with small mistakes in html, as in my example). In those cases, we can't rely on BeautifulSoup for web scraping. Is there any other module to read these sites.

Comment: There is http://scrapy.org/ .

Comment: Thanks. I was looking to it. BeautifulSoup looks easier than scrapy.

Comment: Solved. It may help someone.
Installed "lxml", then it parsed the document properly.