# Extracting Tags from BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the Body-Tag from http://feeds.reuters.com/~r/reuters/technologyNews/~3/ZyAuZq5Cbz0/story01.htm

but BeautifulSoup doesn't find it. Is this because of invalid HTML? If so, how can I prevent this?

I also tried to prefix HTML-Errors using PyTidyLib (http://countergram.com/open-source/pytidylib/docs/index.html)

Here is some of the code:

```
def getContent(url, parser="lxml"):
    request = urllib2.Request(url)  
    try:    
        response = opener.open(request).read()
    except:
        print 'EMPTY CONTENT',url
        return None
    doc, errors = tidy_document(response)
    return parse(url, doc)

def parse(url, response, parser="lxml"):
    try:
        soup = bs(response,parser)
    except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
        if parser=="lxml":
            return parse(url, response, "html5lib")
        else:
            print e,url
            print 'EMPTY CONTENT',url
            return None  

    body = soup.body
    ...
```

When I print out Soup, I can see the opening and closing body-Tag, but after body = soup.body, I get None.

I am using Python 2.7.3 and BeautifulSoup4
It seems to work with BeautifulSoup3, but I need to stick to BS4 due to performance issues.

Comment: This may help you, I had similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15290991/beautifulsoup-not-reading-ill-formed-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it running.
Here is the code:

```
import urllib2
from lxml import html

url = "http://www.reuters.com/article/2013/04/17/us-usa-immigration-tech-idUSBRE93F1DL20130417?feedType=RSS&feedName=technologyNews"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url).read().decode("utf-8")
test = html.fromstring(response)

for p in test.body.iter('p'):
    print p.text_content()
```

Comment: for p in test.body.iter('p'): .. what does the ('p') stands for. is it the <p> tag?