# beautifulsoup soup 4 fails to read all of the html

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a webpage to fetch, when I fetch it with urllib and print the contents, I see the real content length, But after I parse the html with bs4, I see at least 5 blocks of divs are not included to bs4 parsed html, when I parse the html with beautifulsoup, I see the real content, and divs are included, I don't know where is the mistake, but all I see is, bs4 removes some of the divs that are needed by itself, how can I solve this issue ?, here is my sample,

```
#This one does not remove some neccessary parts, This is okay

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen("http://example").read())


#But this one removes some neccessary parts, This is not okay

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen("http://example").read())
```

thank you

Comment: This depends on the (pluggable) parser used; do you have `lxml` installed?

Comment: Also see [Beautiful Soup findAll doen't find them all](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16322862) and [BeautifulSoup fails to parse long view state](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18150786)

Comment: In summary, I suspect that the `lxml` dependencies on your system are somewhat broken.

Comment: @MartijnPieters should I use html.parser for that purpose ? I don't have lxml installed on my system, should I install it ?

Comment: Perhaps, it could be `HTMLLib` parser is at fault here. See the last link where I test 3 different parsers in a loop. `html5lib` might be an idea as well.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thank you very much, I will try all the options

Comment: I had same problem, look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15290991/beautifulsoup-not-reading-ill-formed-html